# Regular expression to clean string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm struggling to figure out even where to start with this. I believe there is a regular expression to make this a fairly straight forward task. I want to trim off the extra asterisks in a string.

Example string:

```
test="AM*BE*3***LAST****~"
```

I would like it to trim asterisks off only the end that don't have repeating symbols. So the resulting value in the variable would be:

```
test="AM*BE*3***LAST~"
```

In Perl I was able to use this:

```
s/\*+~+/~/;
```

Is there something similar I can do in Ruby? I'm sure there is, just struggling to find it for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that `"AM*BE*3***LAST****"` should not be trimmed? The answers assume the last character is `~`. Is that to be hard-wired, or could the last string of askerisks be followed by any characters other than asterisks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
/\*+~$/
```

Then use the `gsub` method to replace all matches with a tilde `~`:

```
test = "AM*BE*3***LAST****~"

test.gsub!(/\*+~$/, '~')
# => "AM*BE*3***LAST~"
```

Or you could use this more flexible regex, which matches any amount of characters after `*` until end of line:

```
/\*+([^*])+$/
```

Then use the first capture group (`$1`) as the replacement:

```
test.gsub(/\*+([^*])+$/) { $1 }
```

Comment: I like that if the last character changes, in this case it won't since its the end of line indicator so always the tilde. Its part of the ASC X12 file format that was picked by Congress to 'simplify' the data exchanges between companies for insurance.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's String class has the [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method, which lets us use regexp as a parameter. We can also assign to that, allowing us to do things like:

```
foo = "AM*BE*3***LAST****~"
foo[/\*+~+$/] = '~'
foo # => "AM*BE*3***LAST~"
```

That reuses the match pattern from your Perl search/replace. (I'm assuming you only want to match at the end of the line because of your examples. If it needs to be anywhere in the string remove the trailing `$` from the pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and try to test the regex and achieve what you need based on the references down the page.

http://rubular.com/